# Loading a local h5 model without top

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

So there is a way to load inbuilt model in tensorflow without top for transfer learning. For example:

```
tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')
```

But how to do the same with a h5 model saved in my pc because `tensorflow.keras.models.load_model` doesnt have `include_top` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22479#issuecomment-472437833):

```
model = load_model("model.h5")
model._layers.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

all layers are accessible in

```py
all_layers = model.layers
```

you can pop the last layer and predict with the remaining layers.

```py
model = load_model('model.h5')
model.layers.pop()
model.predict(inp)
```